# Agregar acción a un QMenu

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Como puedo agregar una accion a un Qmenu de la barra de menu.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para este caso necesito que el boton de Registro me dirija a la segunda pagina del qstackedwidget.

esto he intentado:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QAction
from PyQt5 import uic


class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("nuev.ui",self)

        self.menuRegistro.connect(lambda:self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(2))



app = QApplication([])
p = Principal()
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que usar la señal [`aboutToShow()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#aboutToShow) de QMenu:

```
self.menuRegistro.aboutToShow.connect(lambda : self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(2))
```

Comment: gracias , y una duda recuerdo que algunas vez vi algo como esto self.boton.triggered.signal.connect(), es corrrecto ¿?,

Comment: Cada tipo de widget tiene sus señales, por ello siempre te indico que leas la documentacion

Comment: @ellyanesc, si he leído la documentación pero habeses me confundo con tantas funciones. :)

Comment: @Revsky01 la docs de Qt esta bien ordenada por ejemplo hay una seccion para señales: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#signals y asi para cada las otras secciones