# Desactivar autoseleccion de QMenu

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Una pregunta sencilla como puedo desactivar la auto-selección de un qmenubar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quiero desactivar es la opción de que al hacer click en un Qmenu se queda la accion de click al pasar a los demas botones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese efecto es lanzado por el evento `QEvent::MouseMove` en el QMenuBar, si deseas descartarlo tienes 2 posibles soluciones: el primero es crear una clase que herede QMenuBar y sobreescribir el método `mouseMoveEvent()` eliminando esa tarea, y promoverlo para que lo use Qt Designer, otra solución más sencilla es usar un filtro de eventos, y esa es la que voy mostrar.

Asumiendo el codigo de tu [pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/182090/agregar-acci%C3%B3n-a-un-qmenu) que respondí entonces la solución es la siguiente:

```
class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("nuev.ui",self)

        self.menuBar().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.menuBar() and event.type() == QEvent.MouseMove:
            return True
        return QMainWindow.eventFilter(self, obj, event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = Principal()
    p.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Retornamos `True` ya que queremos que ese evento **no** sea manejado por el QMenuBar, si retomamos False le indicamos que lo debe manejar.